# ¿ Error: (System.StackOverflowException: 'Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.StackOverflowException'.') ¿ Que significa?

Tags: c#

```
namespace algoritmo_por_seleccion2
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Hola, cuantos numeros seran?:");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            llenar b = new llenar(n);

        }

    }
    class llenar
    {
        int[] arreglo;
        int h;

        public llenar(int n)

        {
            h = n;
            arreglo = new int[h];
            Console.WriteLine("Escribe los numeros que iran dentro del array:");
            for (int a = 0; a < h; a++)
            {
                Console.Write("cual es el numero {0}: ", a + 1);
                arreglo[a] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            Quicksort( arreglo, 0, h - 1);
            Imprimir();
        }
        private void Quicksort( int[] array, int primero, int ultimo)
        {

            int i = primero;
            int j = ultimo;
            int pivote = array[(h / 2) - 1];
            int aux;
            do
            {
                while (array[i] < pivote) i++;
                while (array[j] > pivote) j--;
                if (i <= j)
                {
                    aux = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[i];
                    array[i] = aux;
                    i++;
                    j--;


                }
            }
            while (i <= j);
            if (primero < j)
            {
                Quicksort(array, primero, j);
            }
            if (i < ultimo)
            {
                Quicksort(array, i, ultimo);
            }
        }
        private void Imprimir()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Estos son los numero ordenados ");
            for (int a = 0; a < arreglo.Length; a++)
            {
                Console.Write(" " + arreglo[a]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cuando pongo numeros de 1 digito no pasa nada, pero si pongo numeros de dos digitos o mas sale ese error, ayúdenme por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no estás recalculando el índice del pivote, solo cambia la línea

```
int pivote = array[(h / 2) - 1];
```

por esta

```
int pivote = array[(primero+ultimo) / 2 ];
```

Comment: muchas Gracias!!